# How to exectute a Mathematica Script through ssh

Tags: ssh, wolfram-mathematica

here is my problem: i would like to run a Mathematica script through ssh on a remote machine so that i can close the terminal on my computer and keep it running on the remote one.

My problem arises because the script acts in interacting mode, and so when i close the terminal the process is shut down too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [tmux](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1) or [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).

Workflow:

- ssh into remote machine
- start tmux/screen, e.g. `tmux` or `screen`
- start Mathematica script inside tmux/screen session
- detach tmux/screen session, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> (tmux) or <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> (screen)
- close ssh connection

Then later:

- ssh into remote machine
- reattach to tmux/screen session, e.g. `tmux attach` or `screen -d -R`
- view completed Mathematica script output

Answer (score 1):

Several cases:

- If you don't need to interact with it or need to visualize the notebook during evaluation

  1. Log in to the machine with ssh
  2. Then, to run a kernel in the background and detach it from the current session, use `nohup` tool (the standard output of the command will be dumped to myNotebook.out):

     ```
     nohup math < myNotebook.nb > myNotebook.out &
     ```
  3. At this point, the ssh session can be closed without killing Mathematica
  4. Optionally you can monitor `math`command output with the `tail` command (use CTRL-C to exit the `tail` monitoring)

     ```
     tail -f myNotebook.out
     ```
- If you need to see what's going on, visualize graphs during calculation or to be able to interact graphically, use remote desktop (vnc) and tunnel your communication with remote machine. Details depends a bit on the Linux distribution (vnc clients & servers may differ). You can even from Windows or Mac connect with remote desktop to your linux box and manipulate it. I suggest you to search the web for `remote desktop` `ssh tunnel` + your distro for tutorials.